# How to add minutes to a date variable in java

Tags: java

I have a date variable (endTime) with some value (eg : 10:40). I need to create a new variable by adding 10 minutes to endTime. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

```
public static  String endTime = "";
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

endTime = timeFormat.format(cal.getTime());`
```

Comment: Did you consider searching before posting your question?

Comment: Use `LocalTime` and `plusMinutes` of Java 8. It is much simple to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `add` method on your `Calendar`:

```
public static  String endTime = "";
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10)

endTime = timeFormat.format(cal.getTime());`
```

Found in Javadoc, it takes me 30 seconds.

Comment: Answering obvious dupes just makes work for people closing duplicates...

Comment: First thing I do when I see a question is to find a solution. I am working and even if I want to help people, I do not have time to look for the specific same solution on SO.